# How to generate dynamic routes in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a list of houses and each house upon clicking will point to a separate page with data on that house. Currently all the data is static data I created in my constructor - named `leaseData`. I want the `Route path` to point to `/dashboard/lease-id`. I'm trying to pass both the address and the monthlyRent into the `Lease` component so that I can render that data in the new component. How do I do this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Lease } from './Lease'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.match = this.props.match

    this.leaseData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        address: '18291 Rainbow Dr, Cool Springs CA 93102',
        monthlyRent: 4300
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        address: '2200 Stiller Dr, Las Vegas NV 96274',
        monthlyRent: 1500
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        address: '21626 Sleepy Hollow Ct, Walnut CA 91763',
        monthlyRent: 2400
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {

    let linkList = this.leaseData.map(lease => {
      return (
        <li>
          <Link to={`${this.match.url}/${lease.id}`}>
          <img src="https://cdn.edinarealty.com/media/2256/homepage-tiles_new-construction.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon"></img>
          </Link>
        </li>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        MAIN DASHBOARD
        <ul>
         <li> {linkList} </li>
        </ul>
        <Route path={`${this.match.url}/:lease-id`} render={<Lease data={}/>}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright sir friendzone see my solution below and let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Wow thanks for helping me with this issue! One thing I was confused about is what `{...props}` was - you're passing it in both Lease and Dashboard?

Comment: oh yeah! That's not an absolute must to have, but that syntax just means that I want to take all the props from the Router object and make them available to the Lease and Dashboard components. Route has props like match, history and location which can be useful to your rendered components. :) And you can access them inside the component through props.match and etc.

Comment: if you have any other questions regarding this that you need me to clear up, let me know! Also please consider upvoting and marking a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to separate the App and Dashboard logic so we can render things more cleanly.

Here's a sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-merkle-4bxv3

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Lease from "./Lease";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    leaseData: [
      {
        id: 1,
        address: "18291 Rainbow Dr, Cool Springs CA 93102",
        monthlyRent: 4300
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        address: "2200 Stiller Dr, Las Vegas NV 96274",
        monthlyRent: 1500
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        address: "21626 Sleepy Hollow Ct, Walnut CA 91763",
        monthlyRent: 2400
      }
    ],
    selected: null
  };

  changeSelected = id => {
    this.setState({
      selected: this.state.leaseData.find(lease => lease.id == id)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <Dashboard data={this.state.leaseData} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/lease/:id"
          render={props => (
            <Lease
              {...props}
              selected={this.state.selected}
              changeSelected={this.changeSelected}
            />
          )}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    let linkList = this.props.data.map((lease, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <Link to={`/lease/${lease.id}`}>
            <img
              src="https://cdn.edinarealty.com/media/2256/homepage-tiles_new-construction.jpg"
              alt="HTML5 Icon"
            />
          </Link>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        MAIN DASHBOARD
        <ul>{linkList}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Dashboard;

### Lease.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Lease = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    props.changeSelected(id);
  }, []);

  const { selected } = props;

  if (!selected) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Back to home</Link>
        <h4>Id: {selected.id}</h4>
        <h4>Address: {selected.address}</h4>
        <h4>Rent: {selected.monthlyRent}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Lease;
```

**Main notes:**

1. App.js contains our router, lease-data and selected lease.
2. By using the `render` prop we can pass in data from
   the App-state, to the component of the `Route`. For the Dashboard Route, we pass in the entire `lease-data`. For the Lease route, we pass in the `changeSelected()` to help retrieve the selected lease item, and `selected` which is that found item. Additionaly, we spread {...props} to get access to props like `match` and `history`.
3. In Dashboard, we use the same list-generating logic you setup to display the items.
4. When you click an image and get redirected to the `Lease` component, we fire the `changeSelected` function. This happens in `useEffect()`, we use `props.match.params.id` to get the id of the lease (also in the URL) we navigated to via `Link`.
5. Pass that value to changeSelected() and it will update the `selected` value in the App-state with the desginated lease-object in our list.
6. `App.js` gets re-rendered (due to state-change) and passes down the `selected` item state-value to `Lease`, which we will use to display the information on that lease object.

Overall it's a clean-way of doing this before integrating redux.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a router switch and generate your lease routes like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Lease } from './Lease'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.match = this.props.match

    this.leaseData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        address: '18291 Rainbow Dr, Cool Springs CA 93102',
        monthlyRent: 4300
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        address: '2200 Stiller Dr, Las Vegas NV 96274',
        monthlyRent: 1500
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        address: '21626 Sleepy Hollow Ct, Walnut CA 91763',
        monthlyRent: 2400
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {

    let linkList = this.leaseData.map(lease => {
      return (
        <li>
          <Link to={`${this.match.url}/${lease.id}`}>
          <img src="https://cdn.edinarealty.com/media/2256/homepage-tiles_new-construction.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon"></img>
          </Link>
        </li>
      )
    })

    let leaseRoutes = this.leaseData.map(lease => <Route exact path={`${this.match.url}/${lease.id}`} render={<Lease data={lease}/>}/>)

    return (
      <div>
        MAIN DASHBOARD
        <ul>
         <li> {linkList} </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
            {leaseRoutes}
        </Switch>
        <Route path={`${this.match.url}/:lease-id`} render={<Lease data={}/>}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-kalam-m2ejx)

Extract data from `Dashboard` this will let us the ability to look for it by id when `Lease` component mounts

You can replace it with an api call when you implement the backend

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "18291 Rainbow Dr, Cool Springs CA 93102",
    monthlyRent: 4300
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    address: "2200 Stiller Dr, Las Vegas NV 96274",
    monthlyRent: 1500
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    address: "21626 Sleepy Hollow Ct, Walnut CA 91763",
    monthlyRent: 2400
  }
];
```

Extract the leaseId from `match.params.leaseId` and look it up when the component mounts using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) with `leaseId` as a dependency

When you have the api ready you can just replace `data.find` with an API call with the `leaseId`

The reason 'im looking it up on mount is that it will give us the ability to go straight to the URL without needing to go through the dashboard to load the data

```
const Lease = ({
  match: {
    params: { leaseId }
  }
}) => {
  const [leaseData, setLeaseData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLeaseData(data.find(d => d.id.toString() === leaseId));
  }, [leaseId]);

  if (!leaseData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{leaseData.id}</h1>
      <p>{leaseData.address}</p>
      <p>{leaseData.monthlyRent}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When the url is `/dashboard` use the render prop to render the main `Dashboard` and create a `Route` path to leaseId

```
const Dashboard = ({ match: { url } }) => {
  const linkList = data.map(lease => {
    return (
      <li key={lease.id}>
        <Link to={`${url}/${lease.id}`}>
          <img
            src="https://cdn.edinarealty.com/media/2256/homepage-tiles_new-construction.jpg"
            alt="HTML5 Icon"
          />
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path={url}
        render={() => (
          <div>
            MAIN DASHBOARD
            <ul>{linkList}</ul>
          </div>
        )}
      />
      <Route path={`${url}/:leaseId`} component={Lease} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```